# hide scrollbar in safari

Tags: css, ios, safari

i have simple page:

```css
body {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
    scrollbar-width: none;
}
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
.a {
    height: 100px; 
    width: calc(100% - 20px); 
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 7px; 
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="a"></div>
    <div class="a"></div>
    <div class="a"></div>
    <div class="a"></div>
    <div class="a"></div>
    <div class="a"></div>
    <div class="a"></div>
    <div class="a"></div>
    <div class="a"></div>
    <div class="a"></div>
</body>
```

so i tried to hide scrollbar and it's work for android and PC, but on iOS i still can see scrollbar. how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This additional rule using `scrollbar-color` sets the scrollbar color to transparent, effectively hiding it. This should work on iOS devices to hide the scrollbar. Be sure to include this rule with any existing rules you have.

```
/* Hide scrollbar on iOS */
body {
    scrollbar-color: transparent transparent;
}
```

Comment: Did you create this answer with [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1)?